# How many opportunity attacks does moving away from multiple enemies provoke: just one, or one each?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack

I have a quick question on opportunity attacks because I'm either blind or just can't find explanation in the PHB. If multiple PCs are within melee range of an NPC running away, do they each get an opportunity attack?

For example: an NPC is in melee range of two PCs and tries to run away on his turn. PC 1 makes an opportunity attack on the NPC. Does PC 2 get a chance to make an opportunity attack too, or can the NPC no longer be attacked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### *Each* PC refers to the Opportunity Attack rules.

> You [PC] can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature you can see moves out of your reach. (PHB p.195, "Melee Attacks," at "Opportunity Attacks.")

So, each of your PCs who have not used up their reaction and who can see the fleeing NPC get to make the decision: "shall I OA or not?"

Comment: Just to note: ANY creature, PC or not, may use their reaction to make an attack of opportunity on another creature who moves out of their range, i.e. this is not a PC only ability. The NPC's can do it to a PC who runs away just as well.